# Create table with interval column type in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, ddl

What is the syntax of create a table with interval data type in Hive? I tried something like:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 interval year to month);
```

But it doesn't work. Can't find any document from Apache Hive.

Comment: what exactly you are looking for can you give an example or explain...

Comment: The question is simple. Databases like Oracle support interval column type and you can create a table with interval column(http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Interval). Since Hive claims to support interval type, how can I create a table with interval column type?

Answer (score 1):

So far I haven't found a way to directly do it and I'm going to check with some of the Hive Developers to see if this is a bug. The actual data types are interval_day_time and interval_year_month as shown in the work around below. This still doesn't solve the problem on how to create the table with these types directly.

```
create table test_interval 
as 
select  interval '1' day as day_interval, 
        interval '1' month as month_interval;

describe test_interval;
+-----------------+----------------------+----------+--+
|    col_name     |      data_type       | comment  |
+-----------------+----------------------+----------+--+
| day_interval    | interval_day_time    |          |
| month_interval  | interval_year_month  |          |
+-----------------+----------------------+----------+--+
2 rows selected (0.048 seconds)
```

Comment: I submitted issue [HIVE-15692](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15692) on the Apache's Jira Tracker but I haven't seen any it get picked up yet.

Comment: That's weird...

Answer (score 0):

The interval types (YEAR TO MONTH and DAY TIME) are supported only in query expressions and predicates. Interval types are not supported as column data types in tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about pure Spark, but in Databricks, as of 2022, I can specify `INTERVAL DAY` or `INTERVAL MONTH` in `CREATE TABLE`. Other options such as `MINUTE`, `YEAR`, etc, work, too, though they converge to one of those two.

This is not well documented though and the error message when you put just `INTERVAL` alone is misleading.